# SQL Query works in SQL Developer, but not on the Java side

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm trying to figure this but without success. I'm trying to find every row in a specific table that contains a value.

For example, let's consider this Employee table:

```
|     Id           | First_name | Last_name  | Date_of_birth | Car_number |
|------------------|------------|------------|---------------|------------|
| 10001            | John       | Washington | 28-Aug-43     | 5          |
| 10083            | Arvid      | Sharma     | 24-Nov-54     | null       |
| 10034            | David      | Johnson    | 12-May-76     |            |
```

I'm building this query on the Java side (this is what I print in the log):

```
Select * From Employee WHERE Id LIKE ? OR First_name LIKE ? OR Last_name LIKE ? OR Date_of_birth LIKE ? OR Car_number LIKE ?
```

then I use a prepared statement so that, if I search for the string 'oh' it becomes:

```
Select * From Employee WHERE Id LIKE '%oh%' OR First_name LIKE '%oh%' OR Last_name LIKE '%oh%' OR Date_of_birth LIKE '%oh%' OR Car_number LIKE '%oh%'
```

Here's the corresponding code:

```
String wantedQuery = "Select * From " + tableName + " WHERE";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
try(ResultSet rsColumns = columnsForTable(tableName)) {
    String keyword = keywordField.getText();

    int limit = 0;
    while (rsColumns.next()) {
        wantedQuery += " " + rsColumns.getString(1) + " LIKE ? OR";
        limit++;
    }
    wantedQuery = wantedQuery.substring(0, wantedQuery.length()-3);

    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(wantedQuery);

    System.out.println(wantedQuery);
    System.out.println("\'%"+keyword+"%\'");

    for(int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {;
        preparedStatement.setString(i, "\'%"+keyword+"%\'");
    }
}

try(ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
 //now get the results from here
 ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
 while (rs.next()) {
     System.out.println("Fetching row");
     ...
 }
```

Now the problem is that when I try to get the results, it gives me 0 rows (I never see "Fetching row" printed) but the query works in SQL Developer. So I guess the error is on the Java side but I have any clue what it can be. Any ideas?

Comment: As a quick guess, you don't need the single quite signs here: `preparedStatement.setString(i, "\'%"+keyword+"%\'");`

Comment: @meskobalazs Hmm that was it! But it doesn't fetch all the rows. I get like 8 rows but when running the query on the database directly, there are more than one hundred....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `setString()`, JDBC knows that it must be a String, so it puts the single quotes around the `String` as needed, you don't have to do it yourself. But because you do so, it actually a different one, than what you expect.

Comment: Nevermind for my previous comment, I forget to run the query with the same keyword, thanks for the help. `rsColumns.getString(1)` is correct since this is from where I get the columns name from the table (`"Select column_name From USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = ?"`)

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned methods

1. Add spaces at the start and at the end in the query in java code
2. Remove ; from the end of the sql in java code as whenever java code executes sql it appends ; to it.